# Variável de sessão "saldo" não atualiza

Tags: php, session

Estou com um problema que nunca me tinha acontecido antes.  A minha variável de sessão saldo não atualiza na página .php. Ela é atualizada na base de dados depois de um UPDATE. Mas na página só é atualizada se eu fizer logout e voltar a entrar. Qual será o problema?

Estas são as minhas páginas de sessão

```
//init.php
<?php   
session_start(); 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','usbw');   
mysql_select_db('cern_cn');     
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon'); 

?>
```

---

```
//login.php
<?php   
include ('init.php');
include ('con_cern_db.php');    
session_regenerate_id();

//CONSULTA DO UTILIZADOR    
$consulta="Select * from login where username='" . $_POST['username'] . "' and password='" . $_POST['password'] . "' AND saldo AND id";     
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta);  

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0) //SE O EMAIL E A PASSWORD COINCIDIREM     
{       
    //COLOCA NA VARIAVEL LINHA OS DADOS DA CONSULTA         
    $linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado); 
    //COLOCA O EMAIL EM SESSAO 

    $_SESSION['username']=$linha['username'];
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];

    $_SESSION['modo']=$linha['modo'];

    $_SESSION['saldo']=$linha['saldo'];
    $saldo=$_SESSION['saldo'];

    $_SESSION['id']=$linha['id'];
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];

    //REDIRECCIONA A PAGINA PARA A PAGINA SECRETA       
    header("location: index.php");      
}   
else //CASO NAO COINCIDAM   
{   
    //REDIRECCIONA PARA A PAGINA INICIAL REPORTANDO O ERRO
    header("location: index.php?erro=1");  
}        
?>
```

assim é como eu chamo ela

```
<?php            

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) //SE EXISTIR AUTENTICAÇÃO            
 {              

    echo ' Olá ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '.<br/>';        

    echo '  ' . $_SESSION['saldo'] . '.Créditos<br/>';          
    //echo ' Modo ' . $_SESSION['modo'] . '.<br/>';     
   echo " ";

    //--------------------------//              
    //TODO O CODIGO PRIVADO AQUI//              
    //--------------------------//                               

}             
else //CASO NÃO ESTEJA AUTENTICADO             
{               
    echo 'Esta é uma àrea reservada, só utilizadores podem ter acesso.';             
 }      
?>
```

---

```
//logout.php
<?php   
include ('init.php');   
session_destroy();  
header("location: index.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: Provavelmente vc deve estar com a mesma sessao imprima a session id e veja se esta mudando quando vc faz logout depois login. Quando estou com esse "congelamento" de session uso o session_regenerate_id na pagina login assim ele força sempre a gerar um novo id pra sessao. Outra qnd vc faz logout o ideal tbm e limpar a sessao com unset ou destroy.

Comment: Amigo @ThallesDaniel , obrigado pela resposta. Realmente pude reparar que o id de sessão depois do logout era sempre o mesmo. Agora uso o session_regenerate_id(); . O problema continua. O campo está atualizado na base de dados e a minha session saldo não atualiza.O meu logout tem o session_destroy();. O que poderá ser?

Comment: na pagina restrita faça assim:
$_SESSION['saldo']='teste alterando saldo';
E depois assim  print_r($_SESSION); e veja se alterou. O problema pode estar a depender antes da session de um echo no seu select pra ver se exatamente o que ta indo pras session.

Comment: quando estiver dentro da pagina protegida altere o a session com outros valores e de um f5 pra ver se ta alterando

Comment: @ThallesDaniel o problema continua. alterei o saldo para 10. depois atualizei para 15, não deu. Só fazendo logout e login ele atualiza

Comment: ta fazendo local?

Comment: sim, estou com o USBWebServer http://localhost:81/

Comment: tem como testar na web

Comment: vc ja deu um var_dump ou um print na sua consulta pra ver se ta vindo certo?

Comment: Vou testar local em outro computador e na web, amanhã. o problema só pode ser local. Se entretanto conseguires outra solução diz.

Comment: tive um problema com session local tbm por isso perguntei. Tente reiniciar o serviço server.

Comment: Você pode criar uma função que busca no banco de dados se o saldo é o mesmo que está foi setado na session, se for, deixa como true, se não, você coloca $_SESSION[saldo] = $row['saldo'] atualizando a session.

Comment: @ThallesDaniel testei com outro servidor local, easyPHP, e o problema é o mesmo

Comment: Não entendi funcionou ou n?

Comment: não, o problema continua o mesmo

Comment: Tem algo errado na sua aplicação 1.verique $linha['saldo'] antes de atribuir ela na sessao. 2.destrua a session com session array() destroy e unset e lembre de fazer isso sempre colocando session start no topo da pagina. Testa na web pra ver o resultado pq fiz ontem um teste na minha e alterou na hora. Toda página que usa session precisa comecar com session start e nao vi na sua tela de login. E na página logout o correto que eu sei é assim session start e depois session destroy acredito que por isso não ta destruindo.

Comment: Uma duvida, por que está usando `session_regenerate_id`?

Comment: tem vários motivos, session duplicada, problemas pra trocar a session, gerar uma nova etc. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
##########login.php##############
<?php 
include('init.php');
session_start(); 

//CONSULTA DO UTILIZADOR    
$consulta="Select * from login where username='" . $_POST['username'] . "' and password='" . $_POST['password'] . "' AND saldo AND id";     
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta);  

    if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0) //SE O EMAIL E A PASSWORD COINCIDIREM     
    {       
    //COLOCA NA VARIAVEL LINHA OS DADOS DA CONSULTA         
    $linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado); 
    //COLOCA O EMAIL EM SESSAO 

    $_SESSION['username']=$linha['username'];
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];

    $_SESSION['modo']=$linha['modo'];

    $_SESSION['saldo']=$linha['saldo'];
    $saldo=$_SESSION['saldo'];

    $_SESSION['id']=$linha['id'];
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];

    //REDIRECCIONA A PAGINA PARA A PAGINA SECRETA       
    header("location: index.php");      
    }   
    else //CASO NAO COINCIDAM   
    {   
    //REDIRECCIONA PARA A PAGINA INICIAL REPORTANDO O ERRO
    session_destroy();
    header("location: index.php?erro=1");  
    }        
?>


##########privada.php############

<?php            
session_start(); 

    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) //SE EXISTIR AUTENTICAÇÃO            
    {              

    echo ' Olá ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '.<br/>';        
    $_SESSION['saldo'] = '300,00'; #exemplo de receber novo saldo.

    echo '  ' . $_SESSION['saldo'] . '.Créditos<br/>';          
    //echo ' Modo ' . $_SESSION['modo'] . '.<br/>';     
    echo " ";

    //--------------------------//              
    //TODO O CODIGO PRIVADO AQUI//              
    //--------------------------//                               

    }             
    else //CASO NÃO ESTEJA AUTENTICADO             
    {               
    echo 'Esta é uma àrea reservada, só utilizadores podem ter acesso.'; 

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_regenerate_id();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy(); #apenas com esse já resolve tudo mas teste com os outros pra analisar o comportamento
    header("location: login.php"); #voltar para a tela de login 
    }      
?> 



#########logout.php##############

//logout.php
<?php   
session_start(); 
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_regenerate_id();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy(); #se der certo pode remover os anteriores
    header("location: index.php"); 
?>

Fiz um projeto onde tem um var_dump da session e a  alteração de um pagina pra outra

http://sistemasti.16mb.com/david_concha/index.php

Segue código solicitado:



#########index.php###############
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['saldo']='450,00';
    echo 'var_dump($_SESSION) vai retornar o resultado abaxixo</br></br>';
    echo '<pre>'.var_dump($_SESSION).'</pre></br>';
    echo '<pre> Id da session: '.session_id().'</pre></br>';
?>
<a href="index2.php">alterar session na index2</a>



###########index2.php##################
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['saldo']='300,00';
    echo 'var_dump($_SESSION) vai retornar o resultado abaxixo</br></br>';
    echo '<pre>'.var_dump($_SESSION).'</pre></br>';
    echo '<pre> Id da session: '.session_id().'</pre></br>';
?>
<a href="index.php">voltar session com valor anterior na index</a>
```

Comment: sera que me podes enviar o codigo das paginas index e index 2  com "alterar session na index2" "voltar session com valor anterior na index". No seu serviço consigo alterar a sessions sem problema

Comment: @DavidConcha adicionei o que solicitou mas em resumo só coloquei pra a session receber um valor novo na pagina dois $_SESSION['saldo']='300,00'; apenas isso.

Comment: da maneira que tens funciona perfeitamente. se eu atribuir um valor à sessão antes de eu chamar ela se alterar o valor ela altera na hora na pagina

Comment: Não é isso que quer? vc só pode não tem como alterar quando a pagina é exibida para o cliente apenas durante o carregamento de uma pra outra, pq o cliente só o html e não o script que vc fez.

Comment: Eu queria que ele pegasse o novo valor atualizado na bd e mostrasse. ele mostra sempre o valor antigo. se eu atribuir um valor como vc fez ele troca na hora

Comment: então vc faz uma consulta no banco na pagina 2 e coloca pra session receber esse valor novo simples.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29636/discussion-between-thalles-daniel-and-david-concha).